# Creating visibility surfaces through extracting and iterating with ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, visibility

I am using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro.

I am trying to create a short script in order to create visibility surfaces from a set of points and a raster surface. I am new in ArcPy and probably this piece of script is wrong or not so good.

The code I am using:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

env.workspace = r'C:\Users\Me\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\Default.gdb'

## I am calling the proper parameters from ArcGIS Pro documentantion

inRaster = "eleavation"
inObserverFeatures = "points"
aglOutput = r'C:\Users\Me\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\Default.gdb\random'
analysisType = "FREQUENCY"
nonVisibleValue = "ZERO"
zFactor = 1
useEarthCurvature = "FLAT_EARTH"
refractivityCoefficient = 0.13
surfaceOffset = "OFFSETB"
observerElevation = "SPOT"
observerOffset = 1.70
innerRadius = 200
outerRadius = 1000
horizStartAngle = "AZIMUTH1"
horizEndAngle = "AZIMUTH2"
vertUpperAngle = "VERT1"
vertLowerAngle = "VERT2"


## Looping through the points

for x in points:
    outvis = arcpy.sa.Visibility() ## here i use the parameters
    outvis.save()
```

This is the part where I have the problem. I don't know what to include
in outvis.save(). I want to create separate rasters for every point so I though of adding this:

`outvis.save(path + outvis + "\\.tif" + x.`

I think that this is completely wrong and I don't know how to extract it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont have Spatial Analyst so I cant test this but it should work. List all object ids, create a layer from each id using make feature layer and use the layer as input to visibility analysis:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\GIS\ArcMap_default_folder\Default.gdb"
feature_class = r"graphpoints"

all_object_ids = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(feature_class, "OID@")] #List all object ids
#[7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 17, 19, 21, 28]

objectidfield = arcpy.Describe(feature_class).OIDFieldName #Find the object id fieldname
#'OBJECTID'

for pointid in all_object_ids: #For each object id in the object id list
    sql = "{0}={1}".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(datasource=feature_class, field=objectidfield), pointid) #Create a where clause to select only the point with this object id 
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_features=feature_class, out_layer='templayer', where_clause=sql) #Create a layer with only this point in it
    #Insert your visiblity analysis here with 'templayer' as input point layer
    output_raster_name = os.path.join(r'C:\youroutputfolder', "visiblity_analysis_{0}.tif".format(pointid)) #Name the outputs using object id, in my case visiblity_analysis_7.tif, visiblity_analysis_8.tif, ...
    outvis.save(output_raster_name)
```

Comment: I was right, my script was completely wrong. Thanks a lot for your help, it worked like a charm!

Comment: Nice! I wouldnt call it completey wrong. It is not easy for a beginner :)